# counting inversion pair for each array element

Tags: java, arrays

PROBLEM: COUNTING NUMBER OF INVERSIONS FOR EACH ELEMENT IN AN ARRAY

INVERSION: **for any element in an array inversion occurs when a[i] > a[j] and i< j**

Suppose we take an array as an input from the user,
I have to count for each element how many inversions are occurring for every elementt and store them in another array
 for eg.
**

int[] Array={2,1,4,3};**

the expected answer array is

**{1,0,1,0}**

because 2 has 1 inversion pair i.e. (2,1)

1 has no inversion pairs ....so on

**while i am aware how to count total no. of inversions of the array**

```
public int number_inversions(int a[],int n)
{
int count=0;    
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
   {

        if(a[i]>a[j])    
        {count++} ;

   }   
}

   return count;      
}
```

Also the same problem can be solved by manipulating it through mergesort

What i wish to know is how do i get my desired array only through traversal and comparison only without having to use any sorting techniques
IS THAT POSSIBLE?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You replace `int count = 0` with `int[] count = new int[n]`, and `count++` with `count[i]++`.

Comment: as the array you're creating contains only 1's and 0's, try using boolean.

Comment: @Andreas it works, thanks a lot

Comment: @AIaye it is not exactty 1's and 0's it came out to be 1 and 0 for the example i gave and is not in anyway a representation of my expected answer for all such cases , for eg... if i insert a 0 after the 1 in my array the count  array changes as {2,1,0,1,0}